# Determine whether the sequence $\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$ converges and prove your answer using the epsilon method..

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I am having the most trouble with the scratch work ahead of the actual proof. I can't figure out proof of $x_n=\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$ beyond $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Have you tried computing $x_n$ for small $n$, say $0 \leq n \leq 5$?

Comment: The subsequence $x_{2n}\equiv 0$.  The subsequence $x_{4n+1}=1$.    The subsequence $x_{4n+3}=-1$.  Conclude.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Note that the subsequence $x_{2n}\equiv 0$, the subsequence $x_{4n+1}\equiv1$, and the subsequence $x_{4n+3}\equiv-1$.

What can you conclude now?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to consider the actual values of $\sin(n\pi / 2)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to obtain an alternate definition of the sequence.

For example, try $n = 1, 2, 3, 4,...$ and so on, and see if you can find a pattern.  This seems more like a trick question because of that: once you get the other, equivalent sequence, things should be *much* easier.

(You might have to properly justify that the two sequences are equivalent though but that should be easy enough.)

Answer (score 1):

If the series converges to some real number $l$, then $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $|\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}-l|<\varepsilon, \forall n\geq n_0$. It suffices to show that $\exists\varepsilon>0$ for which no such $n_0$ exists.

Say $\varepsilon=1/10$. The interval $(l-\varepsilon, l+\varepsilon)\equiv(l-1/10, l+1/10)$ has length 1/5. Say $\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}\in(l-1/10, l+1/10)$

$\sin \frac{(n+2)\pi}{2}=-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\in(l-1/10, l+1/10)$

or, by the definition of an interval, $(-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}, \sin \frac{n\pi}{2})\subset(l-1/10, l+1/10)$. Whatever be $n_0$ in this case, you can always find a number of the form $n=4m+3\geq n_0, m\in\mathbb N$.

$(-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}, \sin \frac{n\pi}{2})\equiv(-1,1)$

What is the length of this interval?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a_n=x_{2n}=\sin n\pi =0\\b_n=x_{{4n+1}}=\sin {4n+1\over 2}\pi=1$$since $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent to different limits, therefore $x_n$ is not convergent.